# find specific part of string while using sql to query a database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I try to query my database retrieving only part of a field name. Currently I use this code:

```vb
Dim sSQL = "SELECT Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) As [Year], Count([Year]) As [Totals] FROM Archief Group By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) Order By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) DESC ;"
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQL, con3)
    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dt.Load(reader)
    End Using
End Using
```

The field `[Document Name]` contains office documents constructed like:
*MYDOCUMENT.NAME.20210317.DOC*

The code I use retrieves the year 2021 from the date. The problem occurs when the extension has 4 characters, like: *MYDOCUMENT.NAME.20210317.DOCX*

I was wondering if SQL can use code to find the last dot (`.`) in the string and then from there go left 8 characters to find the year.

Comment: Use `Like` in your select statement. If using Access, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/like-operator-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: @user9938 can you give an example?

Comment: Use InStrRev() to find position of that last period. LIKE would be useful in WHERE clause but don't think it is helpful for ORDER BY.

Comment: I believe `CHARINDEX()` is also working in a query. Anyone know how to use that?

Comment: Dim sSQL = "SELECT Substring([Document Name], Charindex('.', REVERSE([Document Name]) - 1, Len([Document Name])) As [Year], Count([Year]) As [Totals] FROM Archief Group By Substring([Document Name], Charindex('.', REVERSE([Document Name]) - 1, Len([Document Name])) Order By Substring([Document Name], Charindex('.', REVERSE([Document Name]) - 1, Len([Document Name])) DESC ;"
tried this code but returns an error

Answer (score 1):

`InstrRev` solved my problem

```
Dim sSQL = "SELECT Mid([Document Name], InstrRev([Document Name], '.', Len([Document Name]) - 1) - 8, 4) As [Year], Count([Year]) As [Totals] FROM Archief Group By Mid([Document Name], InstrRev([Document Name], '.', Len([Document Name]) - 1) - 8, 4) Order By Mid([Document Name], InstrRev([Document Name], '.', Len([Document Name]) - 1) - 8, 4) DESC ;"
```